# JSF - java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, glassfish

Estou desenvolvendo um site em `JSF` mas sou nova em `Web` e não entendo muito bem como funcionam algumas coisas.O site é um `crud` de música simples e faço chamadas a outras aplicações em `jar` que estão na biblioteca para fazer a classificação da música. O problema é que quando eu chamo o método no `bean` para adicionar uma nova música esta dando um erro que não consigo saber o que é ou de onde vem. Qualquer informação ajudaria bastante.

```
   Advertência:   #{musicaBean.adicionar(actionEvent)}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
javax.faces.FacesException: #{musicaBean.adicionar(actionEvent)}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at clare.Clare.<init>(Clare.java:84)
    at br.com.lere.controller.MusicaBean.adicionar(MusicaBean.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more

Grave:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at clare.Clare.<init>(Clare.java:84)
    at br.com.lere.controller.MusicaBean.adicionar(MusicaBean.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 36 more

Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Classe bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MusicaBean implements Serializable {

    private Musica musica;
    private transient DataModel<Musica> listaMusica;

    public void prepararAdicionarMusica(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        musica = new Musica();
    }

    public void prepararMusica(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        musica = (Musica) (listaMusica.getRowData());

    }

    public String adicionar(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws URISyntaxException {
        Clare c = new Clare(musica.getCaminhoxml(),musica.getNome());
        musica.setNivel(c.getMusicLevel());
        musica.setCaminhomidi(c.getMidiFilePath());
        musica.setCaminhoxml(c.getMusicXmlFilePath());
        InterfaceMusica dao = new MusicaDao();
        dao.inserir(musica);
        return "resultado";
    }

    public String alterar(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        InterfaceMusica dao = new MusicaDao();

        dao.alterar(musica);
        return "musica";
    }

    public String excluir(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        File f = new File(musica.getCaminhomidi());
        f.delete();
        f = new File(musica.getCaminhoxml());
        f.delete();
        InterfaceMusica dao = new MusicaDao();
        dao.remover(musica);
        return "musica";
    }

    public Musica getMusica() {
        return musica;
    }

    public void setMusica(Musica musica) {
        this.musica = musica;
    }

    public DataModel<Musica> getListaMusica() {
        List<Musica> lista = new MusicaDao().list();
        listaMusica = new ListDataModel(lista);
        return listaMusica;
    }

    public void setListaMusica(DataModel<Musica> listaMusica) {
        this.listaMusica = listaMusica;
    }

}
```

Classe MusicaDao:

```
public class MusicaDao implements InterfaceMusica {

    @Override
    public Musica getMusica(int id) {
        Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Musica mus = (Musica) ss.load(Musica.class, id);
        HibernateUtil.close(ss);
        return mus;
    }

    @Override
    public void inserir(Musica musica) {
        Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction ts = ss.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ss.save(musica);
            ts.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ts.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
             HibernateUtil.close(ss);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void alterar(Musica musica) {
        Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction ts = ss.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ss.update(musica);
            ts.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ts.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
             HibernateUtil.close(ss);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remover(Musica musica) {
        Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction ts = ss.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ss.delete(musica);
            ts.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ts.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
             HibernateUtil.close(ss);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Musica> list() {
        Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction ts = ss.beginTransaction();
        try {
            List lista = ss.createQuery("From musica ").list();
            ts.commit();
            return lista;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ts.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
           HibernateUtil.close(ss);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Musica> listNome() {
        Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction ts = ss.beginTransaction();
        try {
            List lista = ss.createQuery("From musica ORDER BY nome").list();
            ts.commit();
            return lista;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ts.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
             HibernateUtil.close(ss);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Musica> listNivel() {
        Session ss = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction ts = ss.beginTransaction();
        try {
            List lista = ss.createQuery("From musica ORDER BY nivel").list();
            ts.commit();
            return lista;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ts.rollback();
            throw ex;
        } finally {
             HibernateUtil.close(ss);
        }
    }

}
```

Construtor da classe Clare(jar):

```
public Clare(String musicXmlFileSourcePath, String musicName) throws URISyntaxException {

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss");
        String time = sdf.format(new Date());

        if (!handleXml(time)) {
            System.out.println(erro);
            return;
        } else {
            this.musicXmlFilePath = arquivoXML.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
        }

        if (!handleMidi(time)) {
            System.out.println(erro);
            return;
        } else {
            this.midiFilePath = arquivoMIDI.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/");
        }

 Jsymbolic j = new Jsymbolic();
        String line[] = {arquivoMIDI.getAbsolutePath(), arquivoFEATURES.getAbsolutePath(), arquivoDESC.getAbsolutePath()};

        try {
            if (!j.extract(line)) {
                erro = "Erro ao Extrair Características";
                System.out.println(erro);
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            erro = ex.toString();
            return;
        }

        AceXmlToArff a = new AceXmlToArff();

        if (arquivoFEATURES.exists()) {
            try {
                a.toArff(arquivoFEATURES, ARQUIVO_ARFF_TESTE);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                erro = ex.toString();
                System.out.println(erro);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            erro = "Erro ao Converter para ARFF: Arquivo Features não existe!";
            System.out.println(erro);
            return;
        }

        if (ARQUIVO_ARFF_TESTE.exists()) {
            Weka w = new Weka();
            try {
                w.classify(ARQUIVO_ARFF_TREINAMENTO, ARQUIVO_ARFF_TESTE, ARQUIVO_ARFF_FINAL);
                Nivel n = new Nivel();
                musicLevel = n.find(ARQUIVO_ARFF_FINAL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                erro = e.toString();
                System.out.println(erro);
            }
        } else {
            erro = "Erro na Classificação: Arquivo ARFF Teste não existe!";
            System.out.println(erro);
        }
}
```

Classe jsymbolic(jar):

```
public class Jsymbolic {

    public Jsymbolic() {
    }

    public boolean extract(String[] line) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Extraindo Características...");
        CommandLine c = new CommandLine(line);
         File f = new File(line[1]);
       if(f.exists()){
           System.out.println("Extraídas com sucesso!");
           return true;
       }else{
            System.out.println("ERRO");
            return false;
       }

    }

}
```

Classe CommandLine(jar):

```
public class CommandLine
{
    /**
     * Interprets the command line arguments and begins feature extraction.
     */
    public CommandLine(String[] args)
    {
        // If there are a proper number of command line arguments
        if (args.length == 3)
        {
            extractFeatures(args[0], args[1], args[2], true);
        }

        // If invalid command line arguments are used
        else
        {
            System.err.println("Incorrest usage of jSymbolic. Proper usage requires one of the following:");
            System.err.println("\t1) No arguments: Runs the GUI");
            System.err.println("\t2) <SourceMIDIPath> <FeatureValuesOutputPath> <FeatureDescriptionsOutputPath>");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Extracts all available features from a single MIDI file. Any errors
     * encountered are printed to standard error.
     * 
     * @param input_MIDI_path                   The path of the MIDI file to
     *                                          extract features from.
     * @param feature_values_save_path          The path to save the resulting
     *                                          ACE XML Feature Values file to.
     * @param feature_descriptions_save_path    The path to save the resulting
     *                                          ACE XML Feature Description file
     *                                          to.
     * @param print_log                         Whether or not to print a log
     *                                          of actions to standard out.
     */
    public static void extractFeatures(String input_MIDI_path,
            String feature_values_save_path,
            String feature_descriptions_save_path,
            boolean print_log)
    {
        try
        {
            // Note progress
            if (print_log) System.out.println("jSymbolic is parsing " + input_MIDI_path + "...");

            // Prepare and validate the input file
            File input_MIDI_file = new File(input_MIDI_path);

            FileMethods.validateFile(input_MIDI_file, true, false);
            try {javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(input_MIDI_file);}
            catch (javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException e)
            {
                throw new Exception(input_MIDI_path + " is not a valid MIDI file.");
            }


            // Get all available features
            MIDIFeatureExtractor[] feature_extractors = FeatureSelectorPanel.getAllAvailableFeatureExtractors(null);

            // Choose to extract all features
            // NOTE: could instead get defaults isntead by using non-null argument above for FeatureSelectorPanel.getAllAvailableFeatureExtractors() call
            boolean[] features_to_save = new boolean[feature_extractors.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < features_to_save.length; i++)
                features_to_save[i] = true;

            // Set the default feature extraction parameters
            boolean extract_overall_only = true;
            boolean save_features_for_each_window = false;
            boolean save_overall_recording_features = true;
            double window_size = 1.0;
            double window_overlap = 0.0;

            // Note progress
            if (print_log) System.out.println("jSymbolic is extracting features from " + input_MIDI_path + "...");

            // Prepare to extract features
            MIDIFeatureProcessor processor = new MIDIFeatureProcessor(extract_overall_only,
                window_size,
                window_overlap,
                feature_extractors,
                features_to_save,
                save_features_for_each_window,
                save_overall_recording_features,
                feature_values_save_path,
                feature_descriptions_save_path );

            // Extract features from the MIDI file and save them in an XML file
            processor.extractFeatures(input_MIDI_file);

            // Finalize saved XML files
            processor.finalize();
            // Note progress
            if (print_log) System.out.println("jSymbolic succesfully extracted features from " + input_MIDI_path + "...");
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            // Print a preparatory error message
            System.err.println("JSYMBOLIC ERROR WHILE PROCESSING " + input_MIDI_path + ":");

            // React to the Java Runtime running out of memory
            if (t.toString().startsWith("java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"))
            {
                System.err.println("- The Java Runtime ran out of memory.");
                System.err.println("- Please rerun this program with more more assigned to the runtime heap.");
            }
            else if (t instanceof Exception)
            {
                Exception e = (Exception) t;
                System.err.println("- " + e.getMessage());
                // e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }else{
                            System.err.println("- " + t.toString());
                        }

        }
    }
}
```

O erro geralmente acontece dentro do CommandLine ou logo após.

Comment: Dei uma editada na sua formatação e te da uma dica muito boa para melhorar sua formatação : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: valeu @IgorContini

Comment: Quando você inicia sua aplicação ela ler esse método: public void prepararAdicionarMusica, pois somente nele você esta instanciando musica! Se não instancia musica e ver o que acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Seria interessante postar a classe MusicaDao também.

Parece que estourou uma exception na linha 33 da classe MusicaDao.

```
at br.com.lere.dao.MusicaDao.inserir(MusicaDao.java:33)
```

Se a classe MusicaDao for uma Bean EJB, não seria correto instanciar você mesmo a classe, e sim criar uma EJB como o exemplo abaixo:

```
@EJB
private MusicaDao musicaDao;
```

Comment: oi, obrigada por responder, eu editei la e postei a MusicaDao tbm. A linha 33 é onde chama o metodo save do session do hibernate.
Eu não sei direito o que é o Bean EJB, vou aproveitar dar uma pesquisada, mas se puder postar alguma coisa, agradeço.

Comment: Outras transações (de consulta, por exemplo) utilizando Hibernate neste projeto funcionaram?

Comment: sim, tudo funciona, o adicionar funciona se eu tirar a chamada que faço num jar, por exemplo. Tem vezes que o erro não acontece, mas na maioria das vezes sim. O erro normalmente acontece durante ou depois de chamar metodos desse jar. Dei uma editada no stack trace porque acho que aquele de antes estava dando erro no musicaDao por causa de alguns campos nulos, se puder dar uma olhada de novo agora.

Comment: Qual é a linha 43 do MusicaBean?

at br.com.lere.controller.MusicaBean.adicionar(MusicaBean.java:43)

Comment: (MusicaBean.java:43) se refere a 
Clare c = new Clare(musica.getCaminhoxml(),musica.getNome());
e at clare.Clare.<init>(Clare.java:84) se refere a
Jsymbolic j = new Jsymbolic();

Comment: olha, vou postar todo o resto das classes do jar pra ver se ajuda

Comment: @hapicc estamos nesse forúm para nos ajudar uns aos outros! :)

Comment: Tente adicionar a seguinte linha ao seu `persistence.xml`
`<property name="hibernate.classloading.use_current_tccl_as_parent" value="false" />`